# Visual Studio Code: Flutter: how to efficiently debug on two simulator at the same time

Tags: layout, flutter, visual-studio-code, simulator

When I use `iOS Simulator` to debug with `Flutter` project, if I want to check on `another Simulator` to check if the layout is good on bigger/smaller screen. I found I need to `stop` current project, and click `run` project with another simulator.

And after that, if I directly click the app in previous simulator, I can see the layout isn't the `layout just debugging`, it's `previous layout`.

Which make the debugging with different screen size much inefficient.

Is there anyway to improve the debug process with compare on different screen size much quicker?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simultaneously debug on all connected devices with the `-d all` argument:

```
flutter run -d all
```

Comment: it works, if vscode floating debug bar also support this would be great.